# META Tags "Refresh" Alternative - "<?php header("Location:.. ?>": Issues with php echo in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redirect, meta-tags

I'm working on figuring how to make this code work but just can't seem to crack it.

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://domain-2.com?subid=<?php echo $_GET["subid"]; ?>" /><?php
    die();
?>
```

I understand that it has something to do with the php echo inside the php, is there a way to fix this?

> If none, are the below mentioned worthy contenders or is there something else that I haven't seen that would be the best choice.

The purpose of this is to redirect users to a different page.
The final URL would look like this:

> http://domain-1.com/index.php?subid=subid

What this will do is that it will get the sub-id from the final URL and show stats on a tracker app.
By doing so, there will no longer be a need to change the sub-ids within the .php file.
I can simply add what I want to track outside the .php file & simply FTP just one file to any domain.

I know for sure this code works & is ideally what I'm looking for but,

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com?subid=<?php echo $_GET["subid"]; ?>" />
    </head>
</html>
```

I researched that meta refresh doesn't work on all browsers, which is not good, & that this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>setTimeout('top.location = \'http://example.com?subid=<?php echo $_GET["subid"]; ?>\'', 0000);</script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Is one that I'm not sure will provide a great alternative "open for suggestions though", 
it does work the way it's intended to be, but I'm not totally convinced this would be the next best option.

Much appreciated,
J.c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error correct code will be

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://domain-2.com?subid=".$_GET["subid"]);
    die();
?>
```

Comment: It seems that the <?php echo wasn't needed.
I'll try it out, but I'm sure it'll work by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

It should have to be like this

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://domain-2.com?subid=".$_GET["subid"]." "); 
    die();
?>
```